# Nessus command line tool

Tags: .net, cmd, nessus

There is a question, and I think there is no good documentation on the Internets. So I would to ask your help. I want to invoke nessus, programmatically(Windows, .Net). So I am trying to test the nessuscmd switches and options. The problem is that I cant find how to make it scan with a predefined policy(created from the web interface) and load all the available plugins. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a clear cut way to do so. If you are using Tenable's Security Center 4.x / Nessus, then you should be able to open up a ticket and should get a great response.

Comment: Hi, this post is 9 months ago, so I dont work on it anymore but such functionality would be useful and I will consider opening a ticket. Thanks :)